# how do I properly install twisted using pip?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, twisted

I want to install Twisted 19.7.0 using pip in parrot OS
I have run the command : pip install twisted
But then I am getting an error :
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twisted (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for twisted
How do I fix it?

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You've omitted most of the details of the failure from your question.  This makes it impossible to understand the exact problem you've encountered and therefore quite unlikely that a good answer can be provided.  Please edit the question to include the complete command you are trying to run and the complete output it produces, at least.  Please also include the version of Python and pip you're using (`pip --version` output in particular).

Comment: Actually I am new here, thanks for taking my question. but now I have already been solved the issue so should I delete my Question or edit it for others?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip search twisted` to get the excact module you need, and use :

```
python3 -m pip install <Your selected package name>
```

PS : If you are using code from some repository, check if there is a file called `twisted.py` in the repo. If it exists, place it in the folder along with your code.